# Why am I receiving a SEGV signal (C)?

Tags: c, gcc, memory, memory-management, motif

Contextualizing, after compiling my code I'm receiving a SEGV signal, which is related to unauthorized access of memory. Given the source and that the code was working before recent changes. Why am I receiving this signal?

> Note: Motif's type return explained
>
> *Returns a character pointer to the string value of the TextField widget. This returned
>   value is a copy of the value of the XmNvalue resource. Returns an empty string if
>   the length of the TextField widget’s string is 0 (zero).*

**Declaration:**

```
char *str, *str1, *str2;
```

**Previous initialization:**

```
str2 = XmTextFieldGetString( WIDGET_WITH_STRING );
```

**Current initialization:**

```
str2[0] = "Group Definition";
```

**Exception:**

```
(dbx) cont      
dbx: warning: Resuming only t@1 to satisfy events that require
automatic single-stepping

trace:    814     if (!add_button_sensitive)
trace:    817     str = XmTextFieldGetString( region_code_text );
trace:    818     str1 = XmTextFieldGetString( region_name_text );
trace:    823     str2[0] = "Group Definition";
t@1 (l@1) signal SEGV (access to address exceeded protections) in      
region_add_mod_cb at line 823 in file "region_groups.c"
  823     str2[0] = "Group Definition";
```

Comment: `str2[0]`'s type is char. The assignment makes no sense.

Comment: I figured it out, here's why the signal: ***str2** is declared as a pointer character, I forgot about the dereference operator and created a "pointer array of characters" and tried to assign a string to it.

Comment: Hi Mat, yeah, I forgot to mention that I changed the declaration as well. Surprisingly enough, I spent hours trying to solve this without dbx pointing to the source code.

Comment: If you could formulate more on this subject, assuming there is more to say, please do so as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`str2` is not initialized at all in your code, so it can have any random value. And de-referencing it may cause segfault.

Also `str2[0]` is `char` while you are assigning it a 'char *' `"Group Definition"`, which is not correct. You want `str2 = "Group Definition";` ?

Comment: Hi Rohan, I forgot to mention that I tried declaring ***str2[20]** so the assignment would make sense. As you said, de-referencing was the cause of my problem. Thanks

Comment: @Alan, No that will make twenty pointers, you want twenty characters.

Answer (score 1):

With str2 declared as
  char *str2;
you just need:
  str2 = "Group Definition"